# bash interact just once

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to write a script for Ubuntu, which open a terminal-emulator, which only allows users interact with it only once. After finish running user's first command typed in, the terminal close on itself automatically, which is kind of like Win+R on windows OS.
How should I do that?

I try script like `gnome-terminal -- bash -c "read cmd && $cmd"`, but there's two problem:

1. No auto-complete on user inputting commands;
2. Commands from .bashrc, .bash_aliases are not recognized.

Comment: When my command is `bash`, is your solution than hacked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
gnome-terminal -- bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc; echo 'PROMPT_COMMAND="PROMPT_COMMAND=exit"')
```

I don't have Ubuntu to test at the moment, but `bash ...` part worked.

Comment: Quite nice! It works for bash, and I modified it a little bit to fit gnome-terminal: `gnome-terminal -- bash -c "bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc; echo 'PROMPT_COMMAND=\"PROMPT_COMMAND=exit\"')"`
Thanks!